How to update the time series data value of one field to another field in the same table of Apache IoTDB?
If I want to update the value of field a (if the value of this field exists) of table A to field b of the same table in Apache IoTDB according to the time range, anyone know how to do this? Do I only can re-insert writing data in IoTDB to correct this, or are there any other ways to do this in a more convenient way?

Apache IoTDB includes "view" function that can support different data tree structure based on different perspective, so you can reorganize the fields you need and do not need to in insert the data again in enterprise version.
